# Why is web.config file throwing unrecognized error for unsafe inline in CSP?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config, content-security-policy, penetration-testing

I have tried applying csp in the web.config file of a asp.net web-form project. However, I am getting unrecognized unsafe-inline error.

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value=" 'unsafe-inline'" />.
```

I tried using default-src, safe,  unsafe-eval in the value. all of them are throwing unrecognized errors.

Could you please provide me any resource to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe try this: https://www.sitepoint.com/improving-web-security-with-the-content-security-policy/#setting-header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see this error because specifying `'unsafe-inline'` without a directive is not a valid content security policy definition.

A valid one is made of one or more directives followed by a value, each separated with a semicolon.

The one in your question could look like below.
Notice the directive `default-src` and its value `'unsafe-inline'`.

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'unsafe-inline'" />
```

See this [reference](https://content-security-policy.com) with an overview of directives and values.

Comment: It was still throwing errors. However It got resolved when I used unsafe-eval in this particular case :) . Thanks for the help anyway.